# What's the syntax error in the MySQL statement?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

When using django shell: `python manage.py shell`

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
DE = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
cursor.execute("insert into monitor_regionserver (cluster_id, task_id, name, last_attempt_time, load, numberOfRegions, numberOfRequests, memStoreSizeMB, storefileSizeMB, readRequestsCount, writeRequestsCount, readRequestsCountPerSec, writeRequestsCountPerSec, replication_last_attempt_time, replicationMetrics) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", [30L, 484L, '', DE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, DE, ''])
```

The cursor command looks like this (text-wrapped):

> cursor.execute("insert into monitor_regionserver (cluster_id, task_id, name, last_attempt_time, load, numberOfRegions, numberOfRequests, memStoreSizeMB, storefileSizeMB, readRequestsCount, writeRequestsCount, readRequestsCountPerSec, writeRequestsCountPerSec, replication_last_attempt_time, replicationMetrics) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", [30L, 484L, '', DE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, DE, ''])

I always get the error:

> ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'load, numberOfRegions, numberOfRequests, memStoreSizeMB, storefileSizeMB, readRe' at line 1")

I'm confused with this problem, any idea to share?

Comment: `load` is a reserved keyword

Answer (score 1):

`load` is a keyword in mysql [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

try to rename the column

Comment: Renaming is a solution which might not work out in all situation. You simply have to quote it: `load`.